# Android OutOfMemoryException while saving JSON response to file for parsing

Tags: android, json, out-of-memory

I was getting an OutOfMemoryException trying to simply parse the JSON response as a tree structure using JSON, so I switched to a streaming JSON parsing method. Now, when trying to save the response to a file, I am getting an OutOfMemoryException. Any ideas?

```
  List<CurrencyPair> currencyPairs = new ArrayList<CurrencyPair>();
  URL url = new URL("http://pubapi.cryptsy.com/api.php?method=orderdatav2")

  File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
  File directory = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/zTrader");
  directory.mkdirs();
  File file = new File(directory, "cryptsy_response.json");

  BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
  BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));

  char[] cbuf = new char[255];
  while ((in.read(cbuf)) != -1) { // <-- CRASH HAPPENS HERE
    out.write(cbuf);
  }
  in.close();
  out.close();

  FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
  InputStreamReader fileInputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(fis);
  Reader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileInputStreamReader);
  JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(bufferedReader);

  reader.beginObject();
  Map<CurrencyPair, Integer> newMap = new HashMap<CurrencyPair, Integer>();

  while (reader.hasNext()) {

    String name = reader.nextName();

    if (name.equals("success")) {
      reader.nextInt();
    }
    else if (name.equals("return")) {
      reader.beginObject();

      while (reader.hasNext()) {
        String pairString = reader.nextName();
        String[] currencies = pairString.split("/");
        CurrencyPair currencyPair = new CurrencyPair(currencies[0], currencies[1]);
        currencyPairs.add(currencyPair);

        reader.beginObject();
        while (reader.hasNext()) {
          if (reader.nextName().equals("marketid")) {
            Integer id = Integer.valueOf(reader.nextString());
            newMap.put(currencyPair, id);
          }
          else {
            reader.skipValue();
          }
          if (sleep)
            Thread.sleep(25);
        }
        reader.endObject();
        if (sleep)
          Thread.sleep(25);
      }
    }
  }
  reader.close();
  file.delete();
```

Comment: That particular code looks reasonable, from a memory usage standpoint.  You might want to have a shot at using one of the memory profilers (the new on in Studio is very nice) to get a better idea of what's going on.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the type of Reader that I'm using? Is there another that might be more suitable? Looking at where the crash is happening, it seems like maybe the BufferedReader is causing the issue.

Comment: I suppose you could give a BufferedInputStream a try...  Creating the BufferedReader might be the immediate source of the OOME but people use them in Android code all the time.  That's not the root cause.  There's something else going on.